# Rolling up items based on numeric criteria

Tags: mysql

I am trying to roll up items in Mysql based on a numeric criteria.

In my scenario I have a table of values grouped by account name. I want to generate a % column and ensure that items that aggregate to **<= 15%** are grouped as **'Others'**.

```
SELECT
'EXPENSE' as 'Expense',
"Accounts"."Account Name" as 'Account',
sum("Accrual Transactions"."Transaction Amount") * -1 as 'Total'
FROM  "Accrual Transactions"
JOIN "Accounts" ON "Accrual Transactions"."Account ID"  = "Accounts"."Account ID"  
WHERE    "Accounts"."Account Type"  = 'Expense'
GROUP BY  "Accounts"."Account Name"
ORDER BY 'Total' DESC
```

Based on the above code I have generated the column 'Total' that is sorted by descending order and grouped by account name.

I want to generate a % column that shows % total of each grouped by line item to the grand total. Thereafter items less than or equal to 15% should be displayed as others.

Comment: Please include data / tables as example what you exactly needed here. That could help to understand the issue.

Comment: Hi Vikash. Please find the link for the data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y0tHMROE447N3k5FiuLEsk4XKenKcS52-t4pdM1pQU8/edit?usp=sharing